# Powershell v2 - Split Process.Commandline into parts

Tags: split, powershell-2.0

This seems like something that should be really straightforward, but so far I can't find the way t do it.

I have the below script:

```
    $processName = "notepad.exe"

    $filter = "name like '%"+$processName+"'"
    $result = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter $filter

    $counter=1
    foreach($process in $result )
        {
            $desc = $process.Description
            $commArr = $process.CommandLine -split"( )"
            $comm = $commArr[0]
            $inst = $commArr[2]

            write-host "$counter) -APPLICATION: $desc `r`n   -LOCATION: $comm `r`n   -INSTANCE: $inst"
            $counter++
        }    
}
```

It tells me how many instances of a given application (in this case notepad.exe) are running. It returns the:

```
Application: "notepad.exe"
LOCATION: "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
Instance: " "
```

But for Location I just need the first part `"C:\Windows\system32"`

I tried `split-path` :

`$commShort = split-path($comm)`

but I get the error:
`Split-Path : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"C' does not exist.`

If I try this by manually adding the location though, it works fine:
`$commShort = split-path("C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe")`

Is there some trick to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
$commArr = $process.CommandLine -split"( )"
$comm = $commArr[0]
$inst = $commArr[2]
```

in your for loop with

```
$commArr = $process.CommandLine.Split()
$comm = Split-Path $commArr[0]
$inst = $commArr[1]
```

**The full code:**

```
$processName = "notepad.exe"

$filter = "name like '%"+$processName+"'"
$result = Get-WmiObject win32_process -Filter $filter

$counter=1
foreach($process in $result )
{
    $desc = $process.Description
    $commArr = $process.CommandLine.Split()
    $comm = Split-Path $commArr[0]
    $inst = $commArr[1]

    write-host "$counter) -APPLICATION: $desc `r`n   -LOCATION: $comm `r`n   -INSTANCE: $inst"
    $counter++
}
```

You can also use `Write-Host (Split-Path $process.Path)` to get `C:\Windows\system32` inside you for loop.

Comment: Cheers, the first part failed unfortunately with the same error as originally. However the second part (`Split-Path $process.Path`) works a treat.

Comment: I'm running Powershell v4. I'm running the code using Powershell ISE on Windows 7 32-bit. What version of Windows & Powershell are you using?

Comment: That would probably explain it then. Windows 7 64bit and Powershell v2 (we have some older servers)

Answer (score 0):

To get the parent folder of a path use

```
Split-Path -Parent $thePath
```

The switch parameter `-parent` tells PowerShell to just return the path with the last part cut (but handling root paths).

Comment: cheers, but unfortunately it doesn't work. If I type $commShort = split-path -parent $comm, I still get the error. (adding the process manually works OK e.g $comm = "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe")

Comment: @IGGt I suspect your `$comm` does not have the value you expect it to. (`Write-Debug` and `$DebugPreference` or (for advanced functions) `-Debug` is very helpful.)

Comment: cheers, thats useful to know. Unfortunately it's not the problem in this case: `DEBUG: "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"`

Comment: There must be something special about the string I am using as `test-path $comm` returns false, whereas `test-path "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"` returns true